# morris.js issue with hours on x-axis

Tags: datetime, morris.js

I am trying to create something like the google analytics Audience Overview graph. I am trying to put Hours starting from 12:00am midnight to 11:00pm on the x-axis

This is what I am currently using:

```
Morris.Line({

    element: 'chart_div_compare',

    data: [            
        { hours: '00:00', a: 793, b: 729},
        { hours: '01:00', a: 524, b: 537},
        { hours: '02:00', a: 337, b: 347},
        { hours: '03:00', a: 272, b: 213},
        { hours: '04:00', a: 176, b: 169},
        { hours: '05:00', a: 174, b: 147},
        { hours: '06:00', a: 212, b: 193},
        { hours: '07:00', a: 341, b: 294},
        { hours: '08:00', a: 551, b: 501},
        { hours: '09:00', a: 724, b: 692},
        { hours: '10:00', a: 880, b: 896},
        { hours: '11:00', a: 955, b: 1004},
        { hours: '12:00', a: 1053, b: 1142},
        { hours: '13:00', a: 1063, b: 1150},
        { hours: '14:00', a: 92, b: 1123},
        { hours: '15:00', a: 0, b: 1151},
        { hours: '16:00', a: 0, b: 1222},
        { hours: '17:00', a: 0, b: 1155},
        { hours: '18:00', a: 0, b: 1246},
        { hours: '19:00', a: 0, b: 1100},
        { hours: '20:00', a: 0, b: 1199},
        { hours: '21:00', a: 0, b: 1395},
        { hours: '22:00', a: 0, b: 1361},
        { hours: '23:00', a: 0, b: 1005},
    ],
    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
    xkey: 'hours',
    hideHover: 'auto',
    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
    labels: ['2014-04-16', '2014-04-14']
});
```

The x-axis becomes 1900, 1910, 1920.
Is my format wrong for the hours column?
I cant figure how to get this to graph right but ultimately i would like
12:00 AM, 1:00 AM, etc

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to do this. It should be easy

Comment: Set "parseTime" to false to skip time/date parsing for X values, instead treating them as an equally-spaced series.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I just went into the same problem, maybe you can use the following option:

```
parseTime: false
```

Or you can customize the format method for xlabel. For further information, you can check [this website](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) and [morris on github](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/376).

Comment: Great solution.Thanks.

Comment: For bar charts, "parseTime: false" does not work. Do you know what need to done to show time in proper units for bar charts.