# Morris.js distance instead of years

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I'm kind of new to morris.js and finally got some things work except I don't get how to change values. On the bottom of the charts are years, but I'd like to do distances (let's say KM's / or Miles) and left side minutes.

Example:
[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to get this working?

I'm using the following code:

```
<script>

    Morris.Area({
      element: 'pace',
      data: [
        { distance: '1km', value: 4.30 },
        { distance: '2km', value: 4.35 },
        { distance: '3km', value: 4.21 },
        { distance: '4km', value: 4.30 },
        { distance: '5km', value: 4.35 },
        { distance: '6km', value: 4.35 },
        { distance: '7km', value: 4.30 },
        { distance: '8km', value: 4.40 },
        { distance: '9km', value: 4.34 },
        { distance: '10km', value: 4.32 },
        { distance: '11km', value: 4.20 },
        { distance: '12km', value: 4.19 }       

      ],
      xkey: 'distance',
      // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
      ykeys: ['value'],
      labels: ['Value'],
      lineColors: ['#c20101'],
      fillOpacity: 0.1,  
      pointFillColors: ['#9e0206']
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Could you post a sample demo of what you have and tell what you want to change?

Comment: I think your problem is very close to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116978/morris-js-probelm-with-hours-on-x-axis

Comment: [code]parseTime: false[/code]

Helps, but can't put "KM" behind the distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html, it should work if you set your config like this:

```
parseTime: false,
xLabelFormat: function(x) { return x.label + ' km' }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This results in: [object Object] km . So almost ! :)

Comment: xLabelFormat doesn't work only for line chart. Reference bug https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/494

Comment: @rwzdoorn, I have edited my answer to get the label of the object. It should work.